# How to scrape information from PDFs?

Tags: pdf, web-scraping

I am using Mozenda (Mozenda.com) to scrape an online database, but some of the data is in PDF files. Mozenda does not appear to support scraping these files, so I am looking for another solution.

There are two questions...

1. What is the appropriate XPath syntax to select the URL from a
   link? It is not clear how to do this with Mozenda and the PDF urls
   are necessary to implement a 3rd party solution.
2. What is a good tool to convert large numbers of PDFs online into
   html, or better yet-scrape them?

Any helpful suggestions are most certainly appreciated. I am happy to clarify...just ask.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this is a LATE answer, but Mozenda added the ability to convert PDFs to HTML and scrape from them. It's pretty easy.

https://www.mozenda.com/faqs

Answer (score 0):

using mozenda itself you can create xpath . create any action>refine action> put . in the Xpath and take data whatever you want from CaptureDefination.